# Can I ignore a generic type in a C# interface?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, sieve.net

### Background

I'm starting work on a little OSS library called [Sieve.NET](https://github.com/SeanKilleen/Sieve.NET).

The signature lets someone define a `Sieve` as follows:

```
new EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject>().ForProperty(x => x.AnInt);
```

This actually returns a `Sieve<ABusinessObject, int>`, but I've done my best to ensure that users don't have to care about that part too too much.

### The Task

I would like to find a way to put an interface on this, where I don't care about the property type at all -- only that it is consistent throughout.

So essentially, I would like to be able to declare an `ISieve<TFilterObjectType>`, and by able to have that Interface define something like:

```
ISieve<TFilterObjectType, TTypeIDontCareAbout> ForValue(TTypeIDontCareAbout);
```

My goal is to be able to have a class composed from `ISieve<ABusinessObject>` and not `ISieve<ABusinessObject, int>`.

### Question

- Is there a way for an interface to declare a type that effectively is a wildcard, and says "I don't care what type this is, only that it's consistent?"

My initial research says no but I'm hoping to be proven wrong.

## Updates & Clarifications

What I'm really trying to figure out  is:

- I allow users to create an `EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject>().ForProperty(x=>x.AnInt)`.
- This actually returns an `EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject, int>` to the user, but since it's a fluent interface I remove them from having to care about that part.
- I would like `EqualitySieve`, `LessThanSieve`, etc. to implement `ISieve<ABusinessObject>`.
- I would like `ISieve<ABusinessObject` to enforce a contract whereby I could allow someone to call `ForValues()` and expect it to return an ISieve with the updated values.
- However, at that point, the `EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject>` is actually an `EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject, int>`. But I don't particularly care about the property type at that point.
- Essentially, since I'm abstracting the away the `EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject, int>` portion, I also wanted to see if I could abstract that away when referring to objects via the interface.
- The long-term plan is that I want to have a SieveLocator, where classes can implement an `IFindableSieve<ABusinessObject>` that ideally would return an `ISieve<ABusinessObject>`. Then my goal would be to be able to find those Sieves for a given object.
- So I'm thinking this is likely a limitation of my design and I'll have to find some other way around it. Any suggestions on that or references to a pattern I might not be seeing would be helpful as well.

Comment: @Scott thanks for catching those typos.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain A good point. I think I'm not properly stating my goal enough and am focusing on a technical issue where the problem may be a design issue. I'm going to rephrase. Unfortunately I'm about to jump on a flight so it may have to wait a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place generic type parameters on both the interface and the interface's methods.  So the following example would define a generic interface where the `F` method takes one of these "I don't care what type this is, only that it's consistent" parameters.

```
interface I<T>
{
    //The generic type parameter U is independent of T.
    //Notice how F "forwards" the type U from input to output.
    Tuple<T, U> F<U>(U u);
}
```

Consider the following toy class:

```
class C : I<char>
{
    public char Value { get; set; }
    public Tuple<char, U> F<U>(U u)
    {
        return Tuple.Create(Value, u);
    }
}
```

Here's some example usage:

```
I<char> instance = new C { Value = '!' };
Tuple<char, int> x = instance.F(5); // ('!', 5)
Tuple<char, string> y = instance.F("apple"); // ('!', "apple")
```

## Updates

> - I allow users to create an `EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject>().ForProperty(x=>x.AnInt)`.
> - This actually returns an `EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject, int>` to the user, but since it's a fluent interface I remove them from having to care about that part.
> - I would like `EqualitySieve`, `LessThanSieve`, etc. to implement `ISieve<ABusinessObject>`.

Using the ideas I mentioned above, you can do what (I think) you want.

```
interface ISieve<T>
{
    //It's still not clear what you actually want in this interface...
}

static class Sieve
{
    public EqualitySieve<T> Equality<T>()
    {
        return new EqualitySieve<T>();
    }

    public LessThanSieve<T> LessThan<T>()
    {
        ...
    }
}    

class EqualitySieve<T> : ISieve<T>
{
    //Notice how the property type P is independent of T
    //and can be inferred here from the passed expression
    public EqualitySieve<T, P> ForProperty<P>(
        Expression<Func<T, P>> propertyExpression)
    {
        return new EqualitySieve<T, P>
        {
            PropertyExpression = propertyExpression
        };
    }
}

class EqualitySieve<T, P> : ISieve<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T, P>> PropertyExpression { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
//Assuming MyObject.MyProperty is an int property
//s has type EqualitySieve<MyObject, int>
var s = Sieve.Equality<MyObject>().ForProperty(x => x.MyProperty);
```

Comment: It depends on what he means by "Consistent", if he means that "multiple functions all use the same type" this would not work, but if he means "use of this variable within this function is consistent" then this would work great.

Comment: @Timothy, thank you for response! Sorry for the wait; I added a number of clarifications which I hope will be helpful in terms of my intentions. Please let me know anything else I could clarify. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @SeanKilleen Please see my update and let me know if that's closer.

Comment: @TimothyShields definitely getting closer. Working on a gist to show what I have now to see if it makes more sense. Essentially, I want to be able to write something that will find the `ISieve<ABusinessObject>` and know that when I retrieve it, I can call `ForValues()` on it to apply values. The catch is that forValues cares what property type it is, and I want to do this across multiple types of Sieves. It's tough explain what I'm looking for succinctly. Perhaps the readme.md could clarify goals? https://github.com/SeanKilleen/Sieve.NET

Comment: @SeanKilleen I looked over your github materials and got a better idea of what it is that you're trying to do. It looks like the scope of this question may be creeping larger than originally anticipated, because it's really about how to design the core of a library, not just "how do I get generics to do this one thing." We can continue discussing it via a different medium if you'd like. I might even contribute to it on github since the idea is interesting. I think I could help point you in the right direction of how to do this sort of thing, at the very least.

Comment: Thanks! I think your answer is definitely beyond acceptable for now. The gist is here: https://gist.github.com/SeanKilleen/eb5c94beaed13055cc8c and I've created a chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55080/sieve-net

Comment: FYI, I would love your input and collaboration. I'm glad you see the idea as having some merit. I think we could make a lot of lives easier.

Answer (score 3):

There *may* be some tricks so callers don't need to specify a type on a generic method (think how LINQ works), but unfortunately your research was correct, there is no way to infer a type while composing a class that uses that type.

The closest you can get to it is having two layers of interfaces where the outer layer does not use any of the functions that rely on the `TTypeIDontCareAbout` type.

```
interface ISieve<TFilterObjectType,TTypeIDontCareAbout> : ISieve<TFilterObjectType> 
{
    TFilterObjectType ForValue(TTypeIDontCareAbout forValue);
}

interface ISieve<TFilterObjectType> 
{
    TFilterObjectType SomeOtherFunction();
}
```

---

I don't know how to solve all your problems but I think Timothy's approach is what you want to go for the two points

> - I allow users to create an `EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject>().ForProperty(x=>x.AnInt)`.
> - This actually returns an `EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject, int>` to the user, but since it's a fluent interface I remove them from having to care about that part.

```
interface ISieve<TFilterObjectType> 
{
    TFilterObjectType SomeOtherFunction();
    EqualitySieve<TFilterObjectType, T> ForProperty<T>(Func<TFilterObjectType, T> selector);
    EqualitySieve<TFilterObjectType, T> ForProperty<T>(Expression<Func<TFilterObjectType, T>> selector); //This is how you would do it if you wanted IQueryable support.
}
```

Comment: thanks. I think this is most likely the answer given my clarifications (see the question updates). I was just hoping there would be some trickery that supported it. I'm trying to decide if what I'm doing is some sort of design smell. For findable Sieves, folks will just have to know the property type I suppose.

Comment: @SeanKilleen I think Timothy's approach is the way to go, I updated my answer with a example doing his implementation using the examples you provided.